# Need help getting MAX ID and filling in data and error on ExecuteReader

Tags: vb.net

Ok, so basically what I am trying to accomplish is to get the MAX ID + 1 and display it in the text box and let the user input first name and last name and should be inserted into the database. Currently, I am in the middle of implementing DataAccess.vb as `Dim da As DataAccess` to be used in CustomerForm.vb. Editing customer works fine, the data is being filled in the box and succeeds. However, when Adding customer it does not fill in the box when trying to get the max Id + 1. I get an error when debugging:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'ExecuteReader: Connection property has not been initialized.'

I did try looking online to fix this issue but, and mention that the SqlCommand is not correct. I am getting this error on DataAccess.vb on line `objDataTable.Load(objSqlCommand.ExecuteReader())` . Also would like to note that if editMode is true or false, they both open up CustomerForm.vb

**DataAccess.vb**

```
Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Data.SqlTypes
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.Collections

Public Class DataAccess
    Private connectionString As String
    Private objConnection As SqlConnection
    Public objSqlCommand As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand()
    Private commandText As String
    Public objDataTable As DataTable = New DataTable()

    Public ReadOnly Property Connection As SqlConnection
        Get
            Return Me.objConnection
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Sub New()
        connectionString = ("server=CASHAMERICA; Trusted_Connection=yes; database=ProductsDatabase2; connection timeout=30")
    End Sub

    Public Sub OpenDBConnection()
        objConnection = New SqlConnection(connectionString)
        objConnection.Open()
    End Sub

    Public Sub Parameters(ByVal name As String, ByVal val As Decimal)
        objSqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(name, val)
    End Sub

    Public Sub Parameters(ByVal name As String, ByVal val As String)
        objSqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(name, val)
    End Sub

    Public Sub Parameters(ByVal name As String, ByVal val As Boolean)
        objSqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(name, val)
    End Sub

    Public Sub CreateCommandObject()
        objSqlCommand = objConnection.CreateCommand()
        objSqlCommand.CommandText = commandText
        objSqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    End Sub

    Public Function FillDataTable() As DataTable
        objDataTable = New DataTable()
        objSqlCommand.CommandText = commandText
        objSqlCommand.Connection = objConnection
        objSqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        objDataTable.Load(objSqlCommand.ExecuteReader()) //issue here
        objConnection.Close()
        Return objDataTable
    End Function

    Public Sub CloseConnection()
        If objConnection IsNot Nothing Then objConnection.Close()
    End Sub


End Class
```

**CustomerForm.vb**

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

    Public Class CustomerForm
    Private objConnection As SqlConnection
    Dim da As DataAccess = New DataAccess()
    Public objDataTable As DataTable = New DataTable()
    Public objSqlCommand As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand()
    Public editMode As Boolean = False
    Public id As String = ""
    Public FName As String = ""
    Public LName As String = ""
    Public PhNumber As String = ""

    Public ReadOnly Property Connection As SqlConnection
        Get
            Return Me.objConnection
        End Get
    End Property

    Dim CS As String = ("server=CASHAMERICA;Trusted_Connection=yes;database=ProductsDatabase2; connection timeout=30")

    Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click

        Try
            If editMode = False Then
                If txtFirstName.Text = "" Then
                    MessageBox.Show("First Name Is required")
                ElseIf txtLastName.Text = "" Then
                    MessageBox.Show("Last Name Is required")
                Else
                    Dim con As New SqlConnection(CS)
                    con.Open()
                    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Customers(FIrstName,LastName,PhoneNumber) VALUES(@FName, @LName, @PhNumber)", con)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FName", txtFirstName.Text)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LName", txtLastName.Text)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PhNumber", txtPhoneNumber.Text)
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    MessageBox.Show("Customer has been added!")
                    con.Close()
                End If
            ElseIf editMode = True Then
                If txtFirstName.Text = "" Then
                    MessageBox.Show("First Name Is required")
                ElseIf txtLastName.Text = "" Then
                    MessageBox.Show("Last Name Is required")
                Else
                    Dim con As New SqlConnection(CS)
                    con.Open()
                    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("UPDATE Customers SET FIrstName = @FName, LastName = @LName, PhoneNumber = @PhNumber WHERE Id = @Id", con)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", id)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FName", txtFirstName.Text)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LName", txtLastName.Text)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PhNumber", txtPhoneNumber.Text)
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    MessageBox.Show("Customer has been edited.")
                    con.Close()
                End If
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(Me, ex.Message, "Save Failed", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End Try

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnCancel_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCancel.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub CustomerForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        If editMode = False Then
            GetId()
        Else
            textId.Text = id
            txtFirstName.Text = FName
            txtLastName.Text = LName
            txtPhoneNumber.Text = PhNumber
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub GetId()

    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT MAX(id)+1 FROM Customers")
    da.OpenDBConnection()
    da.CreateCommandObject()
    textId.Text = da.FillDataTable().Rows(0)(0).ToString()
    If textId.Text = "" Then
        textId.Text = "1"
    End If

End Sub



End Class
```

Comment: Your error message is fairly straightforward, the connection hasn't been initialized. Basically what's happening is you're calling FillDataTable prior to calling OpenDbConnection.

Comment: You don't call `da.OpenDBConnection` or `da.CreateCommandObject` before calling `da.FillDataTable`. Instead, you have the `con` and `cmd` local variables that aren't used and, worse, you have no way to assign the `CommandText` for `FillDataTable` to use (you use a field that never gets assigned). The very design of this `DataAccess` class is at the core of the problem. You'd be better off getting out of the plumbing and using something like Dapper.

Comment: On top of that, using `MAX(id) + 1` is a bad idea because multiple users could get the same value and that'll result in primary key violation errors. If `IDENTITY` is not a viable option, consider using a [SEQUENCE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql).

Comment: Ok, I updated method for GetID, but now it says I have not set CommandText Property. Need a solution to set this property. Sorry I will try to fix code.

Comment: Pass it as a parameter to `FillDataTable`.

Comment: Are you saying that I should add this to the Insert method `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", id)` ? I do not know how to pass it as a parameter.

Comment: ***No***. And going back to my original point, get out of the plumbing.

Comment: Would like to know a better way to do this, I am not familiar with Dapper.

Comment: I'm saying that if you stick with this `DataAccess` class, at least have `FillDataTable` accept `commandText As String` as a parameter (remove the field by the same name, it's not doing you any good).

Comment: Like this `Private commandText As String = "SELECT MAX(id)+1 FROM Customers"` ?

Comment: That would not be a parameter.  I mean `Public Function FillDataTable(commandText As String) As DataTable`

Comment: When you are updating a customer where does the original data come form? Where are you getting the Id? Not from GetID. You can't seem to decide if Id is a string or a number. Check your database. What datatype is this field? Is it an Identity field? It should be. If you have any control over the database change this immediately if it is not a numeric Identity.

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarifying. And yes Id is set to Identity and data type is int. And I get the id based on which customer is clicked and passes id to a string.